# What's the equivalent of this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

```
print dir(someOjbect)
```

How can I print that in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, just open up your JavaScript Console or Developer Tools.

```
var red = {color: 'red'};
console.log(red);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and do

```
console.log(someObject);
```

Comment: I usually add `if (!console) { var console = new Object(); console.log = function() {}; }` too somewhere near the top of my scripts for when Firebug is disabled or the browser does not provide console.

Comment: That should be `if (!window.console) ...`, otherwise you'll get an error when it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and dirtiest way is `alert(someObject)`, but it does not help much with objects. You can write a crude `dir()` like this:

```
function dir(obj) {
   var s = '(';
   for (k in obj) {
     v = obj[k];
     if (typeof v != 'function') s += ""+k+":"+v", ";
   }
   return s+")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
console.debug(someOjbect);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a 100% equivalent in JS. However, if you use Firebug's console.log(someObj), you'll see an object in the console that you can click to see its properties.

Alternatively, you can encode and object as json, which will now show any functions that are properties of the object. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

To print in 'console', you are talking about something browser specific. With Firebug and Web Inspector, you can use `console.log(stuff)` to write to the console. If you are actually trying to append to the HTML body, use `document.write(stuff)` or `document.writeln(stuff)`

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has it's own internal console.  If you're using Firefox and have Firebug installed and enabled, you should be able to do something like:

```
console.log(someObject);
```

Depending on how many objects you need to do this for, this works just fine too:

```
alert(someObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.dir(object)` object works fine in Firebug and JS inspectors derived from it.

Beware that not all interpreters support `console` though, so the usual idiom is:

```
if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
  console.dir(object);
}
```

From http://getfirebug.com/logging :

> Object inspection
>
> How many times have you hand-written
>   code to dump all of the properties of
>   an object, or all of the elements in
>   an HTML fragment? With Firebug, you'll
>   never write that code again.
>
> Calling console.dir(object) will log
>   an interactive listing of an object's
>   properties, like a miniature version
>   of the DOM tab. Calling
>   console.dirxml(element) on any HTML or
>   XML element will print a lovely XML
>   outline, like a miniature version of
>   the HTML tab.